# Transpose of csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file in which data is like this

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5
 A,1,3,5,6
 B,2,3,4,5
```

I want to transpose of this file like this:

```
col1,col6,col7
 A,Col1,1
 A,col2,3
 A,col3,5
```

I am using python 2.7. So can I do it using python pandas ?

Comment: The terminology for this kind of transformation is not `transpose`, but **transformation from wide to long format**. There are already some answers available on SO ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `melt`:

```
df.melt(id_vars='col1', var_name='col6', value_name='col7')
```

Output:

```
  col1  col6  col7
0    A  col2     1
1    B  col2     2
2    A  col3     3
3    B  col3     3
4    A  col4     5
5    B  col4     4
6    A  col5     6
7    B  col5     5
```

Option 2 use `set_index` and `stack`:

```
df.set_index('col1').rename_axis('col6', 1).stack().reset_index(name='col7')
```

Output:

```
  col1  col6  col7
0    A  col2     1
1    A  col3     3
2    A  col4     5
3    A  col5     6
4    B  col2     2
5    B  col3     3
6    B  col4     4
7    B  col5     5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Conditional long to wide is possible using pandas?        Like col2, and col2_value is there in col6 and i want col8 which will store col2_value corresponding to col2. And if _value is not for some col6 rows then col8 will be 0

Comment: @keshaw , `unstack` or `pivot`

Comment: Melt and pivot you can kind of think of as doing opposites. You "melt" columns to rows and you "pivot" rows to columns.  Similair with stack and unstack().

Comment: There is a [pd.wide_to_long](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html#pandas-wide-to-long) function.